# Using tensorflow models in web applications

Tags: php, python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

So I've recently became very interested in machine learning, and have been using `tensorflow` (python) in some of my projects at work.

However, I've now found a use for digit classification in one of my web projects which is all written in PHP for server-side code. Ideally, I'd like to be able to upload a picture via a Javascript interface, and on the PHP receiving end process the picture, slide a window to find the set of digits I'm looking for, and then process this through my trained neural network. I guess I'll summarise in one question: ***is this possible?*** Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Tensorflow provides [serving project](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving) for communication, so you need to implement gRPC client for PHP, then use it to talk to Tensorflow serving environment.

That's how I work with Ruby and Tensorflow, it should be working for you as well!

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/api_rest.md

a recent release allowed REST API call from a model server, now you can use curl to perform json queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these PHP extensions:

https://github.com/absalomedia/tensile

https://github.com/wan2land/php-tensorflow

Comment: There is a new one from one of the php core developers.
https://github.com/dstogov/php-tensorflow